# Passar valor do ID pelo Toggle

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte toggle:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele funciona perfeitamente, porém gostaria de colocá-lo de uma forma que funcione individualmente para cada registro que vem do BD, mas não estou conseguindo. Vejam:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .onoff input.toggle {
    display: none;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 1px #d5d5d5;
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    background: #DC143C;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label:before {
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0  Não";
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(19, 191, 17, 0);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.onoff input.toggle:checked + label:before {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 Sim";
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    background: #13bf11;
}
.onoff input.toggle:checked + label:after {
    left: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #13bf11, 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#estado{ font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

**PHP**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Ativo?</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
...
$c = 1;
while($pe = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
{
?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $pe->Nome; ?></td>
     <td>
       <div class="onoff">
         <input type="checkbox" data-id="<?php echo $pe->IdCadastros; ?>"  class="toggle" id="onoff">
         <label for="onoff"></label>
         <input type="hidden" name="Avisar" id="campo<?php echo $c; ?>" value="0">
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
$c++; }
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){

var onoff = document.getElementById('onoff');

onoff.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    estado = this.checked ? 'S' : 'N';
    var campo = document.getElementById("campo1").value = estado;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/status.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
           estado: this.checked,
           campo: campo
       },success: function(data) {
         //alert();
         console.log(data);
        }

      }).done(function(msg) {

   });
});
}//]]>
///////////////////
</script>
```

Como posso fazer para que ele funcione individualmente para cada registro?

Comment: Individualmente que vc se refere eh não precisar usar o seletor por id, para não ter que criar um function para cada nome de id?

Comment: Oi Hugo. Fiz uma alteração no meu post. Na listagem aparecerá o toogle para cada usuário. Preciso para que ao alterar o status para sim ou não, passe o valor do ID do usuário para o Jquery e assim fazer a alteração do Status de cada um no banco de dados.

Comment: Minha dúvida é mais na passagem do ID de cada usuário pelo Toogle pelo Jquery, pois a alteração no BD estou fazendo com o PHP e está tudo oK.

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro o problema, mas de qq forna, não sei responder rss :D

Comment: kkkkkkk tranquilo

Comment: Depois vc vai submeter o formulário todo ou é só esse Ajax mesmo?

Comment: Oi Sam. Isso... fiz uma alteração no meu post. Usei o atributo data-id. Não sei se é o modo correto, mas paree que agora falta apenas passar esse valor pela url.

Comment: troca isso var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); por isso var id = $(".toggle").attr('data-id'); e faz um teste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para não repetir os ids dos botões, concatene a variável `$c` do PHP nos seus ids:

```
id="onoff<?php echo $c; ?>"
```

E o `for` do `label` também:

```
<label for="onoff<?php echo $c; ?>">
```

E poderia fazer assim, pegando o change dos botões pelo id que começam todos iguais com `onoff*`, assim: `$("input[id^='onoff']")`. Ou se só esses botões possuem a classe `.toggle`, pode pegar pela classe: `$(".toggle")`. Mas você pode usar a sintaxe do jQuery mesmo na maior parte do código:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // aguarda o DOM ser carregado

   $("input[id^='onoff']").on("change", function(){

      var id = $(this).data('id');
      var estado = this.checked ? 'S' : 'N';
      var campo = $(this).closest("div").find(":hidden").val(estado);
      $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/status.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
            id: id, // data-id
            estado: estado, // S ou N
            campo: campo[0].id //  id do input hidden
         },
         success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
         }
      }).done(function(msg){
      });

   });

});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   $("input[id^='onoff']").on("change", function(){
      
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      var estado = this.checked ? 'S' : 'N';
      var campo = $(this).closest("div").find(":hidden").val(estado);
      $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/status.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
            id: id, // data-id
            estado: estado, // S ou N
            campo: campo[0].id //  id do input hidden
         },
         success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
         }
      }).done(function(msg){
      });
      
   });
   
});
```

```css
.onoff input.toggle {
    display: none;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 1px #d5d5d5;
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    background: #DC143C;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label:before {
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0  Não";
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(19, 191, 17, 0);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.onoff input.toggle + label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.onoff input.toggle:checked + label:before {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 Sim";
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    background: #13bf11;
}
.onoff input.toggle:checked + label:after {
    left: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #13bf11, 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#estado{ font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Ativo?</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Nome1</td>
     <td>
       <div class="onoff">
         <input type="checkbox" data-id="123" class="toggle" id="onoff1">
         <label for="onoff1"></label>
         <input type="hidden" name="Avisar" id="campo1">
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Nome2</td>
     <td>
       <div class="onoff">
         <input type="checkbox" data-id="456" class="toggle" id="onoff2">
         <label for="onoff2"></label>
         <input type="hidden" name="Avisar" id="campo2">
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oi Sam. Perdoe-me, sobre o botão não consegui compreender. O seu código funcionou, porém só pega no primeiro registro. Acredito que seja realmente algo a ver com o botão que você mencionou.

Comment: Vc tem que concatenar a variável `$c` no `id="onoff"`, da mesma forma que fez no `id="campo<?php echo $c; ?>"`.

Comment: Certo... mas infelizmente não funcionou.... quando concatenei, os botões não mexem mais.....

Comment: Vou adicionar um exemplo funcional na resposta e veja se algo ficou diferente.

Comment: Troquei tb a primeira linha por `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){`.

Comment: Faltou tb colocar o `$c` no label.

Comment: Perfeito Sam... Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado mais uma vez!